# Unable to select range using find and offset functions

Tags: excel, vba, select, offset

My goal is to copy rows from Sheet("VBA") to a specific location in Sheet("COLUMBIA-TAKEDOWN").  The location is Offset(1,1) of the cell containing "P R O S P E C T S".  The first part of my code works well enough however my problems begin with selecting and editing a row [Prospect.Offset(13,-1).Select].  It appears to be ignoring this line of code because the formatting lines that follow are not happening.  It's not throwing out an error message.

I understand that I'm incorrectly selecting the row and therefore unable to make the formatting changes but I don't know how to correct this problem.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Prospect As Range
Set Prospect = Sheets("COLUMBIA-TAKEDOWN").Cells.Find(what:="P R O S P E C T S")

Sheets("VBA").Visible = True
Sheets("VBA").Rows("13:25").Copy
Prospect.Offset(1, -1).Insert shift:=xlDown
Prospect.Offset(13, -1).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Prospects.Offset(1, -1).Select
Sheets("VBA").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I think it may be the "Find()" function but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It's not the `.Find` function. I have just run a simple test on that. Neither is it the `.Prospect` as I previously thought as I have just tested that. Is the VBA sheet locked?

Comment: Is the insert with that offset, they are not the same size.

Comment: Please also post what you want your code to do and pictures of before and after. As of now it's sadly impossible to determine the desired behaviour from your code alone

Comment: From your code it looks like you are trying to insert 12 rows, not just one... see my answer below and see if it meets your needs, if not please clarify what you are trying to achieve as per @Rawrplus advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to [insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) `rows` in a `cell` range... they are not the same size, hence the error.

Give this a try... might need some more thinkering, but i`ve just reused your code.

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ProspectRow As Long: ProspectRow = sht.Cells.Find(what:="P R O S P E C T S").Row + 1

wb.Sheets("VBA").Rows("13:25").Copy
sht.Rows(ProspectRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

With sht.Rows(ProspectRow + 13).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** revamped the code for critics...

**EDIT2:** added the formatting...

Comment: Your code introduces some bad programming practices. Not to mention there are few logical errors such as `ScreenUpdating` being `False` and `Select`ing which will yield to no effect. Also, you shouldn't be using `Select` at all as it's prone to unexpected behaviour

Comment: To add to that, in general I would say the question is very much unclear and impossible to answer correctly. The goal of SO **is not to correct bad code into functional one**, but bad code **into good code with advice on how and why OP should improve it!**

Comment: @Rawrplus thanks... i was looking at the same thing... didn`t like the look of it and just rewrite it, hopefully more to your likeness. I try to help with functional code, and advise wherever... but with a quite simple google/SO search this question wouldn't have been necessary... yet... here we are.

Comment: That's better, but sadly I still don't know whether this is the right answer, given OP needs to add further detail to his question.

Comment: Thanks for all the constructive criticism. I've cleaned up the code a little and copied the entirety of the macro.  I've also updated the description to be more specific.  The problem now lies with selecting the row to perform the formatting changes.  Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: @B-Rye see the updated code... does that work for you? You are still trying to select a full row by selecting a single cell... at least that's what i understand from your description and code.

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks!